# How do I proceed with CompletableFuture without waiting for output

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, completable-future

I got a situation where I need to implement a recursion with `CompletableFuture`. I want to call `recursionFuture(ex)` whenever any of the `CompletableFuture`s returns any result but I am not sure how do I implement that. In the current situation, `recursionFuture(ex)` is called only when both `future1` and `future2` returns output and then if condition is being checked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void recursionFuture(ExecutorService ex) 
    {
        try
        {
            CompletableFuture<Object> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture().executeTask(), ex);  
            CompletableFuture<Object> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture().executeTask(), ex);

            if (future1.get() != null | future2.get() != null)
            { 
                System.out.println("Future1: " + future1.get() + " Future2: " + future2.get());
                recursionFuture(ex);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `anyOf()` with `thenRun()` to achieve that. Just don't call `get()` on both futures because it makes your program to wait for the completion. You can use `isDone()` to check if a future is completed before calling `get()`.

```
CompletableFuture<Object> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture().executeTask(), ex);  
CompletableFuture<Object> future2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture().executeTask(), ex);

CompletableFuture.anyOf(future1, future2).thenRun(() -> {
    if (future1.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Future 1: " + future1.get());
    }
    if (future2.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("Future 2: " + future2.get());
    }
    recursionFuture(ex);
});
```

`anyOf()` will create a new future that will complete as soon as any of the provided futures has completed. `thenRun()` will execute the given `Runnable` as soon as the future it's called on is completed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this works but there is a small problem. due to recursion, code continues even though the executeTask() doesn't return any thing and goes on indefinitely. Is it possible to put a check on the output of future like futire1.get() != null then call recursion but with the earlier stated problem happens. Can you advise here please.

Comment: Well, I got this working by editing code like: CompletableFuture.anyOf(future1, future2).thenRunAsync(()-> 
   {
    recursionFuture(ex);
   }
     , ex);

Answer (score 0):

If you only use two CompletableFutures, you could also have a look at runAfterEither / runAfterEitherAsync. There are also versions which allow to access the value returned like acceptEither / acceptEitherAsync.